# Commit window on Android Studio says "bad config line 12 in file .git/config"

Tags: git, android-studio, git-config

I recently switched my github repo from public to private. In doing so, the new commit "went through" but did not show up on the repo; instead, I got a 404 error when I "open on Github." I realized it may be because my tags were limited to "HEAD" and "master" and was missing "origin/master". This was what I tried:

```
git init
git checkout -B master origin/master
fatal: 'origin/master' is not a commit and a branch 'master' cannot be created from it
```

I got back to my Android Studio project and it says "bad config line 12 in file .git/config" So this is what I suspect to be the issue (in notepad):

```
[remote "origin"] //line 8
url = https://github.com/user/applicationname.git //not the actual url, but I know this line is fine
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*[branch "master"]  

remote = origin //line 12
merge = refs/heads/master
```

In which remote = origin is line 12. I also double checked with directory:

```
git rev-parse --git-dir
.git
```

I pushed a few times while it was public. And I can still open up the previous commits' webpage via Version Control: Log.

Comment: Looks like you should have a newline before and after `[branch master]` but this is very unclear. Is this line 12 of the config file?

Comment: You're right. It's stuck on line 10. Foolish of me not to use a code editor. Thanks tripleee!

Comment: Still looks like you lack a newline before `[branch "master"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still looks like you lack a newline before `[branch "master"]`. Without it, it's looking like you're trying to set a `remote` for the `[remote]` which I guess you can't. The stuff in brackets is supposed to start a new section but because of the missing newline, it's instead botching the value of the `fetch =` setting which should be the previous line.

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://github.com/user/applicationname.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

[branch "master"]  
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```